# How to set id and class of DropDownFor - asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a small mvc applicaiton and using DropDownListFor in it. Iam unable to set an id and class for that dropdownlist. Following is my DropdownListFor code in which i want to add Id and class. Timely help will be appreciated, thanks

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.Student.StudentId, new SelectList(Model.StudentList, "StudentId", "FirstName"), "--Select--")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**`@Html.DropDownListFor`** In html helpers If you want to add any html attribute you have to pass them as objects of `htmlAttributes` type , Like explained by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Where htmlAttributes are

```
Type: System.Object
An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element
```

So as your question goes

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.Student.StudentId, new SelectList(Model.StudentList, "StudentId", "FirstName"), "--Select--",new { @id="myid", @class="myclass" })
```

where `new` keyword creates an object for htmlattributes

Answer (score 5):

In order to set `id` and `class` of `@Html.DropDownListFor` use below code :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.Student.StudentId, new SelectList(Model.StudentList, "StudentId", "FirstName"), "--Select--",new { @id="myid", @class="myclass" })
```

**In order to set html attributes inside `@Html.DropDownListFor`, you have to set 4th parameter of `@Html.DropDownListFor` with `new` keyword which will create a `object` for `htmlattributes`.**