# DropDownListFor has unique value for all items

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using a razor helper `DropDownListFor` in order to have a dropdown list of Organizational Units from Active Directory (replicated in Database, it doesn't matter so much). The idea is you have a first list with all parent elements, and when clicking, I search my database to find the children elements, and so on until you reach a leaf (so to speak, last element). My problem is that when inspecting element in my browser I find that all `value` from the `<option>` markup are equal to the first id that I pass when clicking.

So here is my ViewModel:

```
public class SiteDirectionModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Then my first controller method (for parent elements) is the following :

```
public ActionResult CreateADUser()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    SiteDirectionModel sdM = new SiteDirectionModel();

    //The below method gets all parent nodes from database
    //_nonGenService is an instance of a service that can access my Repository
    direction = _nonGenService.GetAllSiteDirection();
    if (direction != null && direction.Count!=0)
    {
        items.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = dir.Name, 
            Value = dir.IDDirection.ToString()
        });
     }
     sdM.Names = items;
     return View(sdM);
    }
    else
        return View("AccessError"); //A page in case of error 
}
```

Then the second controller method to treat child elements:

```
public ActionResult GetSiteRF(SiteDirectionModel model)
{
    SiteDirectionModel sdM = new SiteDirectionModel();
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    //This method gets children elements from a specified id
    //The table that looks has IDDirection as FK from first table
    radioFrance = _nonGenService.GetSiteRFFromDirection(model.id);
    direction = _nonGenService.GetAllSiteDirection();
    int id;
    string nameConcat = string.Empty;
    //For loop to concatenate names
    foreach(var dir in direction)
    {
        if (dir.IDDirection == model.id)
        {
            nameConcat = dir.Name + "-" + nameConcat;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (radioFrance.Count==1)
    {//This condition would be to see if the name is equal to the current node so 
     //that we can exit the condition and access a form to create the user
        Site_RadioFrance single = radioFrance.SingleOrDefault();
        if (single.Name.Equals(nameConcat))
        {
            return View("CreateADForm", model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var radio in radioFrance)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = nameConcat+radio.Name,
                Value = radio.IDDirection.ToString()
            });  
        }
        sdM.Names = items;
        return View("CreateADUser",sdM);
    }
    return View("AccessError"); //Error treatement
}
```

My view loks like this :

```
@model MyProject.Models.SiteDirectionModel
<h2>Create an account in Active Directory</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSiteRF", "Create", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.id, Model.Names);
    <input type="submit" value="Selectionner" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
```

Now say you have the item clicked with `IDDirection=10` then all my child elements have

```
<option value=10>parent1-child1</option>
<option value=10>parent1-child2</option>
<option value=10>parent1-child3</option>
<option value=10>parent1-child4</option>
```

I don't know how to fix this, any ideas? because then my model id has this value, and I somehow thought that it would apply a value for each different option, I don't understand why it doesn't?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `Value = radio.IDDirection.ToString()` is a good assignment? As you should know, the DDLF value attribute comes from `Value` property of a `SelectListItem`.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054026/how-to-set-id-and-class-of-dropdownfor-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I'm not sure I understand what you mean, the ID I need is indeed `radio.IDDirection` which I convert to string so it can be passed. so technically, for a new ID, the for loop goes through new values doesn't it?

Comment: @AbhayDixit I'd seen this post and I think it's related as to using stytling on the helper. I need an ID passed to my controller. That's why I want to use it as a value. It works onthe first level, but once you acces child elements it doesn't. thanks though :)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes you are right, it's the wrong assignment because IDDirection is parent so I give parent to all child elements  ... Thanks :)

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.id, new SelectList(Model.Names, "Value", "Text ")

Comment: @VigneshPandi What Testuya suggested fixed it for me, though I realize I've got some BL problems.